# Scrapy Request callback not being fired

Tags: scrapy, rules

I'm playing around with scraping infos from Amazon, but it's giving me a hard time. My spider looks like this so far:

```
class AmzCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'amz_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&bbn=1267449011&page=1&rh=n%3A284507%2Cn%3A1055398%2Cn%3A%211063498%2Cn%3A1267449011%2Cn%3A3204211011']

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"page=\d+"), callback="parse_item", follow= True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        category_name = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="nav-subnav"]/a[1]/text()').extract()[0]
        products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="s-item-container"]')

        for product in products:
            item = AmzItem()
            item['title'] = product.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "s-access-detail-page")]/@title').extract()[0]
            item['url'] = product.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "s-access-detail-page")]/@href').extract()[0]
            request = scrapy.Request(item['url'], callback=self.parse_product)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            print "Crawl " + item["title"]
            print "Crawl " + item['url']
            yield request

    def parse_product(self, response):
        print ( "Parse Product" )
        item = response.meta['item']
        sel = Selector(response)
        item['asin'] = sel.xpath('//td[@class="bucket"]/div/ul/li/b[contains(text(),"ASIN:")]/../text()').extract()[0]

        return item
```

There are two issues which I don't seem to understand:
'Parse Product' is never printed - so I assume the method parse_product is never being executed even though the prints with Crawl  ... are nicely displayed.
Maybe it's about the Rules?

And then related to the rules:
It's only working for the first page of a category. The crawler doesn't follow links to the 2nd page of a category.
I assume that the pages for Scrapy are generated in a different way then for the browser? In the console I see a lot of 301 redirects:

> 2015-06-30 14:57:24+0800 [amz_crawler] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A2619533011%2Ck%3Apet%20supplies%2Cp_72%3A2661618011%2Cp_n_date_first_available_absolute%3A2661609011> from http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_pg_1?sf=qz&fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A2619533011%2Ck%3Apet+supplies%2Cp_n_date_first_available_absolute%3A2661609011%2Cp_72%3A2661618011&sort=date-desc-rank&keywords=pet+supplies&ie=UTF8&qid=1435312739>
>   2015-06-30 14:57:29+0800 [amz_crawler] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A2619533011%2Ck%3Apet%20supplies%2Cp_72%3A2661618011%2Cp_n_date_first_available_absolute%3A2661609011> (referer: None)
>   2015-06-30 14:57:39+0800 [amz_crawler] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A2619533011%2Cp_72%3A2661618011> (referer: http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A2619533011%2Ck%3Apet%20supplies%2Cp_72%3A2661618011%2Cp_n_date_first_available_absolute%3A2661609011)
>   Crawl 2015-06-30 14:57:39 Precious Cat Ultra Premium Clumping Cat Litter, 40 pound bag
>   Crawl [http://www.amazon.com/Precious-Cat-Premium-Clumping-Litter/dp/B0009X29WK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0009X29WK)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I've just tried running it (I've just replaced print with `inspect_response` which pauses the job and lets you inspect the response (like `scrapy shell`) and it works. My code: http://susepaste.org/53347438

Comment: That's strange - just copied your code and tried it but `inspect_response(response, self)
        print("Parse Product")` are not being executed - even after several minutes.  `print "Crawl " +` is being executed frequently.
I've got Scrapy 0.24.6 and Python 2.7.6 - how about you?

Comment: I'm running the same versions as well, though it shouldn't really matter. Maybe some project settings are modifying your results? Try `scrapy startproject` and then recreate the spider in the new project.

Comment: Yes .. seems to be working with a new crawler - but not exactly as I expected it (wrong rules I guess) - I'll keep on digging and see whether I can find out where the problem came from. Thanks